How to restrict user from running queries that change data
I have a large Java based application that uses connection pooling to access the underlying database for all sort of CURD and reporting operations. The application also provides a database query interface to run various queries. As the same connection pool is used to run these queries as the rest of the application, I wonder how can I restrict users to run only SELECT queries. My fear is that a user might intentionally or accidentally Drop a table or delete/modify records which will be horrible. Any easy solution without having to use a separate connection pool or a read-only user?

Why don't you create a user with only "Select" permission,  what is the problem with it?

Will have to maintain a separate pool because of large number of application users

Don't use the same connection pool as the rest of the application, use a separate connection pool with a user that only has select privileges. Alternatively, you could try to mark the connection read-only before using it in such a query interface. However, I'm not sure if that works on Oracle or not.

@AnR Also how DB user is related to Application user? Multiple application user can use same DB user that's how it works.

Apparently read-only connection is not recommended in some posts

@PradeepSimha Its a single DB user that all Application users use via pool

@AnR, unless your Java code implements 100% of your security and is not hackable (and given that you are concerned about users doing bad things, it sounds like it does not implement sufficient security), you must use a different database user for non-privileged vs. privileged users. That's how Oracle implements security. There's no other way to protect your data if you can't rely 100% on your client-level security. Any sane program would implement security at both layers, especially since any code running on a client machine is vulnerable.


Any easy solution without having to use a separate connection pool or a read-only user?

The proper solution to this IS to create a second database user and GRANT that user only the SELECT privilege on the tables and modify your application to connect only to that user; then it is impossible for them to modify or drop the tables.
If your application is written so that you always use queries in the form of:
SELECT column_names
FROM   schema_name.table_name

Where you always specify the schema_name in the query then you should only need to modify the connection to connect to the restricted user and the rest of the application should work identically.
If you haven't specified the schema_name prefix then you would need to add this to your queries (or else add aliases to your database user).

If you are relying on a third-party application to protect your data by not using DELETE or DROP statements when connected to a privileged user that would allow those operations then you have not fully-secured that application and are relying on the social contract with the developer to continue never using those statements (as there is nothing that actually prevents them from using those statements beyond that social contract).  If you want to forbid those statements then connect to a non-privileged user where the database will enforce the user's privileges.

As well as prefixing or creating synonyms, you could also issue an alter session set current_schema=... on each JDBC connection to see that schema's objects by default.

With Spring JPA you can use Read-Only Transactions :
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<MyEntity> findAll() {
        return myRepository.findAll();
    }
}

Or you can change Database User Permissions, for example, in MySQL:
GRANT SELECT ON mydb.* TO 'read_only_user'@'localhost';

